# Spring Boot 2.3.2 server.forward-headers-strategy=framework redirects to scheme http instead of https

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, openid-connect

I'm currently migrating an old application using Spring Boot 2.0.x to more recent Spring Boot 2.3.x version.
The app is deployed on OpenShift behind a reverse-proxy (apache) to handle the SSL certificate.

The app is using a openid-connect system to authenticate the user.
Basically the openid-connect server redirects the user to /login (via redirect-uri) and after, via a custom implementation of Spring class SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler and his method "onAuthenticationSuccess", we redirect the user to /profile via a default redirect strategy.

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private final RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy;


    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        // We do some stuff here...
        log.debug("Redirecting to /profile");
        log.debug("request.getScheme() = " + request.getScheme());
        log.debug("request.getContextPath() = " + request.getContextPath());
        log.debug("request.getRequestURI() = " + request.getRequestURI());
        log.debug("request.getRequestURL() = " + request.getRequestURL().toString());
        log.debug("request.getServletPath() = " + request.getServletPath());
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/profile");
    }

}
```

With the Spring Boot version 2.0.x, no problem, everything was working fine.
After the migration to Spring Boot version 2.3.x, the user was redirect to http://**INTERNAL_OPENSHIFT_HOST**/ourApp/profile

I found the "new" parameter introduced since Spring Boot 2.2 called **server.forward-headers-strategy**.
If I set the value to "framework", then the redirect is done to **http**://REVERSE_PROXY_HOST/ourApp/profile

And well... I have no idea **why http is used instead of https**! I suppose everything is correctly setup on the reverse-proxy side because well everything was fine with Spring Boot 2.0.x!

I probably miss something... another parameter of something similar but I'm currently stuck on that point...
Any idea?

Comment: is this in external tomcat environment or is it embedded tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following property:

```
server.tomcat.redirect-context-root = false
```

source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22908